# Cannot create an instant of the interface firebaseauthprovider

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a wpf app for a school project and i thought it would be a good idea to implement firebase authentication  to my application, and i found a video reference url:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCEOdnd0-so&list=PLA8ZIAm2I03jn4cDxYTqi40DOHjoOYZCz&index=1

even though i got my window to open when i tried to create a dummy user i get an error(can not create an instant of the interface firebaseauthprovider). I will put code inside my app.xaml.cs file below. It would be a great help if someone could identify the solution for my problem. thank you.

```
using Firebase.Auth;
using Firebase.Auth.Providers;
using Firebase.Auth.Repository;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;



namespace Key_Auth.wpf
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {

        private readonly IHost host;

        public App()
        {
            // Build the host
            host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    // Load configuration from appsettings.json
                    config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

                })
                .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                {
                    //get firebase api from configuration
                    string firebaseApiKey = context.Configuration["FIREBASE_API_KEY"];

                    services.AddSingleton<FirebaseAuthProvider>((serviceProvider) =>
                    {
                        // Create a new FirebaseAuthProvider instance with the API key

//here throws me an error
                        var authProvider = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(firebaseApiKey));

                        // Do any additional configuration here, such as setting up a user change event handler

                        return authProvider;
                    });

                    // Register FirebaseAuthProvider as a singleton with a callback

                    // Register services here
                    // For example:
                    // services.AddSingleton<MyService>();
                    // services.AddTransient<MyOtherService>();
                    services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();

                    // Register MainWindow as a singleton with a callback
                    services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>((serviceProvider) =>
                    {
                        // Get any required dependencies and create the MainWindow instance
                        var mainWindow = new MainWindow();

                        // Do any additional configuration here

                        return mainWindow;
                    });


                })
                .Build();
        }

        protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            /*
            base.OnStartup(e);

            // Start the host
            await host.StartAsync();

            // Resolve the main window from the service provider
            var mainWindow = host.Services.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>();

            // Show the main window
            mainWindow.Show();
            */

            base.OnStartup(e);

            // Start the host
            await host.StartAsync();

            // Resolve the main window from the service provider
            var mainWindow = host.Services.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>();

            // Set the main window of the application
            MainWindow = mainWindow;

            // Show the main window
            mainWindow.Show();


            //provider.GetService<FirebaseAuthProvider>();
            //GetRequiredService<FirebaseAuthProvider>();
     
        }

        protected override async void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnExit(e);

            // Shutdown the host
            await host.StopAsync();
            host.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

i want to create a FirebaseAuthProvider that is imported from firebase.auth

Comment: Have you looked through the docs?  Unity is c#.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/start

Comment: no I haven't. thank you so much @Andy for  pointing me to the official documentation.

Comment: that is not c# but unity. where is c# getting started page?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project nuget package manager and downgrade the `FirebaseAuthentication.net` package you installed to the exact version used in the video tutorial (i.e. version 3.7.2). Only then will you be able to create an instant of `FirebaseAuthProvider` and you will be able to follow the tutorial. Also, be mindful that the tutorial's project is a `WPF` `.Net` project and not `.Net Framework`.

Update:

If you wish to continue with the latest version, however, you can check the examples of usage on the [package's nuget webpage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FirebaseAuthentication.net)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of work, here is the code that made it work. read below and understand it. But basically we are using `projectId`, `firebaseAuthConfig`, inside we have the `Apikey`, `AuthDomain` that brings the `projectId`, and we need the providers with `FirebaseAuthProvider`.

I Followed the Nuget Doc and i was using .NET 7 and Firebase 4.1.0.
The code is a Controller in a .NET webApp.

```cs
[NonAction]
public async Task<string> SubirStorage(Stream archivo, string nombre)
{
  string ApiKey = _firebaseStorage.ApiKey;
  string AuthPassword = _firebaseStorage.AuthPassword;
  string AuthEmail = _firebaseStorage.AuthEmail;
  string StorageUrl = _firebaseStorage.StorageUrl;
  string projectId = _firebaseStorage.projectId;
  var config = new FirebaseAuthConfig
  {
    ApiKey = ApiKey,
    AuthDomain = $"{projectId}.firebaseapp.com",
    Providers = new FirebaseAuthProvider[]{
                new EmailProvider()
            }
  };
  var client = new FirebaseAuthClient(config);
  var a = await client.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(AuthEmail, AuthPassword);
  var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();

  var task = new FirebaseStorage(
      StorageUrl,
      new FirebaseStorageOptions
      {
        AuthTokenAsyncFactory = async () => await a.User.GetIdTokenAsync(),
        ThrowOnCancel = true
      })
      .Child("imagenes")
      .Child(nombre)
      .PutAsync(archivo, cancellation.Token);

  var downloadURL = await task;
  return downloadURL;
}
```